# Creation of new objects slows down?

Tags: php, object, new-operator

I was searching why my script slows down with a growing number of objects. But I could not find an error on my side. The script is just creating objects. I've disabled all possible variables.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $ilen; $i++)
{
    $row = db_row($res, $i);
    echo str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", str_pad("obj" . $i, 10)); 
    $time = microtime(true);
    $element = new dataStructureElement($row['code']);
    echo "New: " . number_format((microtime(true) - $time) * 1000, 1) . "ms\n";
}

class dataStructureElement {

...

function __construct($code, $recover = false)
{
    $time = microtime(true);
    parent::__construct();
    $this->code = $code = enc::seourl($code);
    $this->key = 'element:' . $code;

    if ($recover) $this->recover();

    $this->properties = new dataStructureProperties($code);
    $this->rules = new dataStructurePropertiesRules($code);

    $this->searchIndex = new dataSearchIndexElement($code);
    $this->searchGroup = new dataSearchGroupElement($code);
    echo "__constuct(): " . number_format((microtime(true) - $time) * 1000000, 1) . "&micro;s ";

}

...

}


obj0      __constuct(): 4,512.8µs New: 5.6ms  
obj1      __constuct(): 150.9µs New: 1.5ms  
obj2      __constuct(): 149.0µs New: 1.2ms  
obj3      __constuct(): 141.1µs New: 1.1ms  
obj4      __constuct(): 142.8µs New: 1.1ms  
obj5      __constuct(): 140.9µs New: 1.1ms  
obj6      __constuct(): 197.9µs New: 1.4ms  

...

obj1993   __constuct(): 237.9µs New: 11.3ms
obj1994   __constuct(): 245.1µs New: 11.8ms  
obj1995   __constuct(): 240.8µs New: 18.9ms  
obj1996   __constuct(): 250.1µs New: 12.0ms  
obj1997   __constuct(): 303.0µs New: 12.3ms  
obj1998   __constuct(): 252.0µs New: 12.4ms  
obj1999   __constuct(): 338.1µs New: 12.3ms
```

The first has a high time because of the include() in the autoloader. __construct() has some new sub objects but don't raises as fast as the original new operator. I thought accessing an object is done by a handler in O(1) and not in O(n). I'm using PHP 5.2.3.

Anyone with a helpful advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Update: I've added unset($element); in the loop an the last time is as high as the first. (lucky guess) But WHY is that so?

Comment: You would probably be well served to upgrade past 5.3, a log of improvements have been made to the garbage collector.

Comment: I will try it with 5.3 later. But the effect of an "unset" at the end of the loop is really tremendous. Now it is at obj1      __constuct(): 172.1µs New: 0.2ms  and obj1999   __constuct(): 193.1µs New: 0.2ms.